# Grant only one one user to specific azure database and restrict all users from that database

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I have one azure SQL server **PPP** with Four Database.

```
Database are :  A , B, C and D.
```

And there some azure AD groups and members which have access to this **PPP** Server.

So all AD members having access to all four database.

but my Requirement is to give only permission to user "Ram" and restrict access from all other users for Database D.

So only user ram can access database D. Even Ram can access all other database.

How I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can Alter the permission of the users or you can go to the particular Azure SQL database and remove the users from there which users are not required. Generally the Login is created in Server and users are created one each databases accordingly. If the users are created in master database then it will be difficult to restrict the permissions.